# How to search on FHIR using the field on reference resource

Tags: hapi-fhir

I want to return search results of `medicationRequest` using the `episodeOfCare` id. An `episodeOfCare` is available on on `encounter` resource which is a reference on `medicationRequest` resource. Would anyone help me on how to to search for medication requests using the episode of care ID? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use chain searching for querying the medicationRequest by EpisodeOfCare.id: `{base}/MedicationRequest?encounter.episode-of-care._id=123`

Comment: Thanks. This has worked. I was using ```episodeOfcare``` instead of ```episode-of-care```!

Comment: This is a correct answer. Another difficult way to answer your question is to configure the search parameter FHIR resource. But just take it as a consideration.